# VBA Expand/Collapse rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report in which I am asking the users to click buttons to reveal where they need to add their commentary. I have it working but wanted to put in an If statement in case they have already expanded the row.

I have two macros, the first relates to the button they push and sends to the main macro the name of the button and a row number which is part of the section that is either expanded or collapsed

```
Sub ROccupancy()
'
Dim RecName As String
RecName = "ROccupancy"
Dim RowNum As Integer
RowNum = 27

Call ToogleRec(RecName, RowNum)

End Sub
```

The next macro is where I am having the trouble

```
Sub ToogleRec(RecName, RowNum)
'
Dim Toogle As String
Dim MyObj As Object

Set MyObj = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(RecName))

Toogle = Left(MyObj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text, 4)
TextName = Mid(MyObj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text, 5, 100)
If Toogle = "Show" Then
    MyObj.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset9
    MyObj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Hide" & TextName
    MsgBox Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail
        If Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = False Then
            Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = True
        End If


Else
    MyObj.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset11
    MyObj.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Show" & TextName
    MsgBox Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail
        If Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = True Then
            Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = False
        End If
End If
Range("C" & RowNum).Select
End Sub
```

The issue is the Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail is always TRUE, no matter if it's expanded or collapsed. I can remove the If section and set it to TRUE or FALSE using "Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = False" or "Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail = TRUE". However, if the user has manually expanded or collapsed the row it causes an error (which freaks them out)

This question and answer seemed [promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863752/vba-expand-collapse-rows-with-same-macro-button) but Rows(RowNum).ShowDetail always seems to be TRUE

I put the MsgBox in there for error checking. I'll remove it in the final version.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/86445-showdetail.html  the rows you're trying to toggle part of a pivottable or subtotals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `Hidden` property? Something like:

```
With Sheet1.Rows(5)
    .ShowDetail = .Hidden
End With
```

Take note though that for you to use `.ShowDetail` method, 
you'll need to `Group` the rows first ([needs to be in outline form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-showdetail-property-excel)).

> True if the outline is expanded for the specified range (so that the detail of the column or row is visible). The specified range must be a single summary column or row in an ***outline***.

Above code toggles hiding/unhiding a grouped row 5. 
 You don't even need an `If` statement for the toggling. HTH.

Comment: Thanks. I have the sections grouped and your solution definitely works.

Silly question - how come it works?

Comment: @IHamilton Yeah silly bro, I don't know the answer too. Tim's solution in the thread you posted should've worked. I only happen to use the `Hidden` property before so I thought to give it a try on `Outlined` sheet and share it with you. It somehow works. Cheers! :)